# RubyOnRails / building full tree from deeply nested relational models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, object, activerecord

Having the following self relational many-to-many setup :

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :joins, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :child_items, through: :joins
end

class Join < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item
  belongs_to :child_item, class_name: 'Item'
end
```

What would be the most straightforward pattern to rebuild a json representation of the full tree ? Like:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    child_items: [
      {
        id: 2,
        child_items: [
          {
            id: 3,
            child_items: etc… untils there are no more
          }
        ]
    ]
  }, {
    id: 4,
    child_items: { etc... }
  }, etc…
]
```

So far I have the simple following :

```
def render
  iterate(entrypoint_item)
end

def iterate(node)
  h = JSON.parse(node.to_json)
  h['child_items'] = []
  node.child_items.collect{ |child|
    h['child_items'] << iterate(child)
  }
  h.delete('child_items') if h['child_items'].length <= 0
  h
end
```

Is there a more ruby/rails-way to accomplish this ?

Comment: except the undetermined `JSON.parse(node.to_json)`, its ok

Comment: maybe try `node.as_json` ?

Comment: what is actually not great is that it would lead to many db queries, this is where gems like ancestry thrive as the get all your tree members in one query

Comment: @apneadiving agree for the queries that's why i'm asking; that is, I've checked that gem some time ago as it sounded like the go-to; but if I'm not mistaking, you don't get many-to-many handling, right ? from 2012, but sounded like https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/issues/94#issuecomment-6755069 it would never ever be planned

Comment: many to many feels weird in a tree though but yeah I can understand you would need it

Comment: am building a menu for an estore; for example having a 'men' and 'women' category, a given 'shirt' category can be nested in both. unfortunately ancestry "owns" its children, so felt like going this way; but I'm still learning

Comment: tried such http://www.portailsig.org/content/postgresql-focus-sur-les-requetes-sql-recursives as it would limit the queries to a single function call; but am unable to completely understand the syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should give you some inspiration:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :joins, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :child_items, through: :joins

  def as_json_iterated
    options = {}
    chain_length.times { options[:include] = {child_items: options} }
    as_json(options)
  end

  def chain_length(counter = 0)
    return counter if child_items.empty?
    child_items.map { |item| item.chain_length(counter + 1) }.max
  end

end
```

This results in:

```
Item.find(1).as_json_iterated
#=> {
#     "id"=>1, 
#     "child_items"=>[{
#       "id"=>2, 
#       "child_items"=>[{
#         "id"=>4, 
#         "child_items"=>[{
#           "id"=>7,  
#           "child_items"=>[]
#         }]
#       }, {
#         "id"=>5, 
#         "child_items"=>[]
#       }]
#     }, {
#       "id"=>3,  
#       "child_items"=>[{
#         "id"=>6,
#         "child_items"=>[]
#       }]
#     }]
#   }
```

**Keep in mind that this method has some terrible SQL performance.**

For more info about the *#as_json* options see: *[ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)*

Comment: anyone would admit the poor sql performance, the question is here to get a nicer alternative. While I don't see the use case being that evil (let's say you'll dig 2 levels deep most of the time, that just keep the ability to nest further), am a bit deceived not to see a decent alternative. Looked into serializers, checked again as you're linking; it runs a single sql query for each includes — if Im' not wrong, you get the same poor performance. I might not look into the right direction, but am wondering